# beginner flash - delay frame for X seconds then continue

Tags: flash

i have a very simple animation in flash CS4. My image travels from point X to point Y over 90 frames. I would like the image to stop at frame 45 for a few seconds, before continuing.

how would i achieve this

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this actionscript to the frame 45:

```
    stop();
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);
    myTimer.start();
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent){
        play();
    });
```